# Solr hostname fails

Tags: solr, jetty

I have installed Solr on a windows server VM.  The Solr admin is accessible via localhost. But It isn't accessible via my hostname.  The DNS is setup correctly, Dhost has the proper hostname value.  It's as if jetty is not listening.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If using a modern browser, and connecting via HTTPS, you must use a real hostname, (not localhost, or an IP address).

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, as such it's not suitable for Stackoverflow.  Perhaps you'll have more luck on the sister site for Stackoverflow called https://serverfault.com/ which is focused on configuring and managing server software.